# Solving the equation: $\cos(x)= \cos(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'll be glad if someone could explain the justification of this solution:

$$\cos(x)=\cos(2x),\; [0^{\circ},360^{\circ})$$

$$\Rightarrow x=\pm2x+360^{\circ}k,\; k\in\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow x=0^{\circ}, 120^{\circ}, 240^{\circ}$$

How come I can cancel the "cos" like that?

My solution is:

$$\cos(2x)-\cos(x)=0 \Rightarrow (2\cos^{2}x-1)-\cos(x)=0 \Rightarrow \cos x=1 ,\; \cos x=-\frac{1}{2} $$

Then: $x=0^{\circ}, 120^{\circ}, 240^{\circ}$

Thanks.

Comment: You can apply $\arccos$ at both sides...

Comment: @vonbrand - how?

Comment: It is always permissible to apply the same operation to both sides of an equality...

Comment: i know, just don't understand how is it different from the first equation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\cos x = \cos y$ when **and only when** $x = y + 360 k$ or $x = -y + 360 k$.  Use these two relations to obtain the first method.  This follows from the definition of $\cos x$ being the horizontal component of an angle $x$ on the unit circle.  Only (at most) two points have the same horizontal component, namely angle $x$ and $-x$.

Comment: so if $sin(x)=sin(180^{0}-x)$ i can say: $x=180^{0}-x+360^{0}k$, or, $x=180^{0}-(180^{0}-x)+360^{0}k$? that will get me to:$x=90^{0}+180^{0}k$

Comment: In the case of $\sin$, $\sin x = \sin y$ when and only when $x = y + 360k$ or $x = 180 - y + 360k$.  Letting $y = 180 - x$ gets what you said in the comment.  Note that the second equation will show that this equation is always true since the two $x$'s cancel out.

Comment: but isn't the identity $sin(x)=sin(180^{0}-x)$ is true for any angle? if we got to $x=90^{0}+180^{0}k$ is it not for any angle? thanks for your help.

Comment: It is true for any angle, the second equation $$x = 180^{\circ} - (180^{\circ} - x) + 360^{\circ} k$$ reduces down to $$ 0^{\circ} = 360^{\circ} k$$ which is true for any $x$.

Comment: Do you mean for the unit circle? because for $k=1$ we get: $0^{\circ}\neq 360^{\circ}$

Comment: There is an implicit "for some $k$" in the above equations.  In particular, the above equation holds for $k = 0$

Comment: so for the identity $sin(x)=sin(180^{\circ}-x)$ it holds just for $k=0$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use $\cos (2x)= 2 \cos^2(x)-1$.

$2 \cos^2(x)-1=\cos(x)$

Take $\cos(x)=y$

$2y^2-1-y=0 \implies (2y+1)(y-1)=0$

**Justification for your effort**:

$\cos(x)=\cos(2x)$

$\cos(x)= \cos(360^\circ \pm 2x)$,

You know that $x \neq 2x$ (Except for $x=0$). So, you must have $x=360 \pm 2x$.

Comment: This is fine but just letting you know OP already did it this way and is trying to understand the alternative method suggested

Answer (score 0):

We know $$\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)=2\sin A\sin B$$

For $\cos x=\cos 2x,x=A-B,A+B=2x\implies A=\frac{3x}2, B=\frac x2$

So, $\cos x-\cos 2x=0\implies 2\sin \frac{3x}2\sin \frac x2=0 $

If $\sin \frac x2=0, \frac x2=n180^\circ\implies x=n 360^\circ$ where $n$ is any integer

If $\sin \frac{3x}2=0, \frac{3x}2=m180^\circ\implies x=m120^\circ$ where $m$ is any integer

Observe that the second set is a super-set of the first

So, we need $0\le 120m<360\iff 0\le m<3$

Comment: $2n\pi$ or $360n$! which one is better? I prefer the first one as you used, lab.

Comment: thanks but how does it answer my question?

Comment: @user64370: Consider two "If" in his answer.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Solving_Trigonometric_Equations